# tiMidity: extract tracks preserving initial silence

Tags: audio, sync, extract, midi

`tiMidity` can extract individual tracks from a standard MIDI file to audio files, using its option `-o out.wav`, and its option `-Q 0,-n` to quieten all tracks but the n'th.

However, re-mixing the resulting .wav files (`sox -m *.wav ...`) may *not* reconstitute the original (all tracks, without `-Q`).  This is because any track whose first note-on event comes several seconds after the overall start (i.e., starts with a rest) produces an audio file that starts exactly at the first note.  Noble, but misguided.

How can a single track be extracted into an audio file, preserving any silence *before* the first note?

(Must I edit the MIDI file to insert, into each track, a dummy zero-volume note at the start of the music?  Or add a dummy track `m` with a zero-volume starting note, and then `-Q 0,-n,-m` ?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

timidity version 2.14.0 has an option `--preserve-silence` which prevents it from dropping the initial rests.

Comment: Indeed, 2.14.0 from sourceforge's timidity.c includes this option.  Yay!  It just hasn't yet reached Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, whose timidity package is still 2.13.2.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is *still* stuck at timidity 2.13.2.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS is **still** stuck at timidity 2.13.2.

Comment: I’d guess that’s coming straight from debian, where [there doesn’t seem to be much packaging activity](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=timidity&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).  On the other hand, version 2.14.x isn’t mentioned on [the timidity++ sourceforge page](http://timidity.sourceforge.net/) either.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS is ...... you guessed it!

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, at last, has timidity 2.14.  There, `timidity --help` mentions this option, but the manpage is still stuck at 2.13.  Good grief.